# jaysvcutil failing with TypeError: Cannot read property 'schemas' of undefined

Tags: jaydata

I am trying to generate the model from an existing OData service through jaysvcutil and am getting:

```
[...]\node_modules\jaydata-odatajs\lib\odata\odatautils.js:385
            throw err;
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'schemas' of undefined
    at Metadata.processMetadata ([...]\node_modules\jaydata-dynamic-metadata\lib\metadata.js:353:35)
    at requestData ([...]\node_modules\jaydata-dynamic-metadata\lib\metadataHandler.js:46:42)
    at [...]\node_modules\jaydata-odatajs\lib\odata\odatautils.js:382:13
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> ([...]\node_modules\jaydata-odatajs\lib\odata\net.js:179:21)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

I tried to condense the domain model into something really simple, so my current $metadata looks like this:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
        <Schema xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm" Namespace="data">
            <EntityType Name="Product">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ProductId"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ProductId" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="ProductNo" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
                <Property Name="LifeTime" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="Capacity" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="PackingSize" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="CreationTime" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="ModificationTime" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm" Namespace="Namespace">
            <EntityContainer Name="DomainData" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="Product" EntityType="data.Product"/>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

This is an existing WCF DataService based OData provider using OData V1 and I am not able to change that - so please do not recommend updating the provider to V4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per feedback from the JayData team:

```
JayData supports OData v4, as there have been multiple breaking changes in both OData and DataJS since v1.
```

and also

```
JayData 1.3.7 supports v2 and v3, but it does not support TypeScript and Angular 2.
```

I will therefore be looking at alternatives, presumably breezejs.